# Java libraries for converting between character encodings

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

The problem I am looking to solve is converting between unicode storage types. As I understand it, one character in UTF-8 can be represented by 1 to 4 bytes of data whereas a character in UTF-16 can be represented in 1-2, two bytes blocks of data. This variable length means it's a pain to convert between the two and produce something that is sensible in the english language.

What I am looking for is a library that would let me specify a language or locale, and a storage mechanism (utf-8 etc.) and have it produce a more sensible result. Am I dreaming in the clouds?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sensible in English language"? Whether it is sensible in English is irrelevant to encoding. If you just need to convert from one encoding to another, then Herms' answer is right.

Comment: I know, it's irrelevant to encoding. I want to do something more than just convert from one encoding to another. I want to convert to a different encoding given a locale, and then get a result that is sensible (meaning you can look it up in an english dictionary if the locale represents an english language),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `String.getBytes(String charsetname)` not sufficient?

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29)

It lets you get the raw bytes of a String in a particular encoding.

String has a [constructor][2] that will take a byte array and charset name as well, so you can use that for decoding.

[2]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], java.lang.String)

Comment: Yeah, no that converts the raw bytes to whatever encoding you specify, but as far as I understand it, is dumb. I mean, it's not looking to produce the best representation in the english language of the utf-8 string "hello" in utf-16.

Comment: I'm saying you take your UTF-8 string and create a String from it.  Then use getBytes() to convert that string to the UTF-16 bytes you want (or whatever combination of input/output you have).

Comment: Strange, my 2nd link shows as a link in the preview, but not in the actual page.

Comment: But how do you convert it to the bytes you want? As I understand it, you give getBytes a byte array and character set (utf-8 etc) and it just converts the raw bytes to the charset you specify. It doesn't do any calculations to determine which representation of the string in the new charset makes the most sense for the english language.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by "makes the most sense in the english language".  The UTFs are just character encodings.  Java will convert the logical characters into the correct bytes for the encoding you asked for.  I don't see how language comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert bytes in one encoding to a Java String via the constructor String(byte[], Charset). Supported character sets are listed in [java.nio.charset.Charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

You can then convert back to bytes with a different encoding with `String.getBytes(CharSet)`.

For example:

```
byte[] bytesIn = ...;
String s = new String( bytesIn, Charset.forName( "UTF-8" );
byte[] bytesOut = s.getBytes( Charset.forName( "UTF-16" ))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is sensible for a lot of character sets.  There's still a few that can't fit into Unicode, but not many.

First remember that the bytes are not characters, to deal with characters you need to convert them, and typically the easiest way to do that is to wrap a Byte Stream in a Reader (or Writer) which was constructed with the appropriate encoding / decoding set.

For a list of directly supported encodings, [here's what comes with the JVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html#charenc).

The key is not to use default Readers and Writers, as they use the platform's encoding.  Instead pick one encoding.  UTF-8 is good on disk size, poor on encoding / decoding performance; while UTF-32 is horrible on disk size and excellent on encoding / decoding performance.  UTF-16 is something of a compromise.  All UTF based encodings optimize to handle ASCII characters a bit more efficiently, so UTF-8 might beat UTF-16 if you are only dealing with mostly ASCII.

Note that you cannot convert bytes into a new character set, they are "casted" to the new character set.  That means if you want to convert bytes to a new character set, you must turn them into Strings or Characters and the get the bytes of the string in the new character set.

One way to read a byte stream as an InputStream with your own specified Character Set is to use a [InputStreamReader constructed with an alternate character set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).  Likewise, you need to use an OutputStreamWriter constructed with an alternate character set.

All files that you don't manage directly should use the platform character set (since that's probably what they will be) and be converted to the character set of choice when being saved or inputted into the program.

Comment: I know both utf-8 and utf-16 represent unicode, but they represent it differently right? So won't there always potentially be a loss of representation of a word when converting between them?

Comment: No there will be not potential for loss.  UTF-8 tries to represent UTF-32 using storage blocks of 8 bits.  Basically if it cannot represent everything within the 8 bits (minus a some overhead) then it starts adding more 8 bit blocks to handle the extra information.  It is similar to trimming leading zeros on a number.  UTF-16 basically does the same thing, but it's rules on adding extra storage are less complicated, and since it starts with more bits, it needs to store one char in multiple blocks less often.  UTF-32 uses 32 bits, and it trims nothing and needs no expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [java.io.Reader/Writer](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/ProgIOStreams/) or [java.nio.charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html)?